# ( Autoresizing mask ) flexible width of an image with fixed height

Tags: iphone, width, mask, autoresize

I have been playing around with iPhone interface building using only code and not using IB.

Now I'm facing the following problem:

How can I set an image to have a width based on the main view it is located on and to let it have a margin of for example 50 pixels on both sides. ( it should also work with rotation so the width should be flexible ).

I have tried setting the size with frame.size.width - 50 for example but this doesn't work when the screen rotates. Another thing I tried is using the autoresizing masks but I'm not completely understanding how this works.

Does one still need to set a frame for an image or is this completely overruled by the autoresizing masks? And if it's overruled how can I give the image a fixed height and a flexible width?

The book I'm using ( advanced iOS4 programming ) is not very clear in this matter and most examples I find on the net are for interface builder.

Thanks for your time.

Kind regards,
Jasper

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Horizontally:

- Resize keeping fixed left/right margins: `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth`
- Keep size and same distance from the left: `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin`
- Keep size, stay centered: `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin`
- Keep size and same distance from the right: `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin`

Vertically:

- Resize keeping fixed top/bottom margins: `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight`
- Keep size and same distance from the top: `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin`
- Keep size, stay centered: `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin`
- Keep size and same distance from the bottom: `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin`

Combine one from the first section with one from the second with a `|`. For example, to have it resize horizontally and keep the same size and distance from the top vertically, you'd use `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin`.

You can use other combinations to do some more tricky things, but those are the basics.

Comment: So basically how I now see it.. you set the frame for a certain object. and then you specify these values in case the screen rotates so it knows how to respond ?

Comment: Yes, or in case the superview changes size for any other reason. For example, the "in-call status bar" could appear causing the top-level UINavigationController to resize its content area, or you could just change the `frame` of the superview for reasons of your own.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want this:

```
[myImageView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];
```

That will keep the margins static and resize the width.

Comment: this is what I tried doing, but how will I set the height for this image then if I want that to be fixed?

Comment: If you don’t set the height to be flexible, the height won’t change.