# How to change the size of text fields when turned to landscape Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, uikit, interface-builder

I am creating an iPad app which is a form with mostly text boxes. When the iPad is portrait, it displays the text fields vertically in two columns. When I turn the iPad landscape, it still displays the text fields the same exact way except there is open space to the right of the screen. My question is- When the text box is turned landscape, how do you increase the size of the labels and text fields to fill in the open space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a XIB use the inspector to make sure you have the layout guides set to fixed so the width of the text field are at a constant length from the XIB edge - thereby stretching the text field when the interface orientation changes.

If you are laying out your view in code implement the following in your [UIViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) subclass:

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration{

    [super willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation duration:duration];

    if( UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(toInterfaceOrientation) ){
        // Adjust your text field...
    } else if( UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation) ){
        // Adjust your text field...
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, do you know how to allow a label and a text field to float (move to a different position) when turned to landscape?

Comment: You are always free to set a new origin coordinate for your labels and text fields manually. If at all possible use the Autosizing masks as described in answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5169517

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your struts & springs of the textfield are correctly set!
Here is what you should set in Interface Builder:

[image]

And if you doing this with code here is the code:

```
myTextField.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin
```

either way you have to set this to every textfield in you form.

Comment: Thanks, helped me. I never really noticed this autorezizing feature :-)