# UITableViewCell contentView button disappear after changing Orientation in iOS 6

Tags: ios, uitableview

```
 if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation))
 {
    //Landscape mode.
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)  //Frame for iPad
    {
        [deleteButton setFrame:CGRectMake(984, 7, 30, 30)];
        [editButton setFrame:CGRectMake(944, 7, 30, 30)];
    }
    else
    {
        if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height==568)
        {
            [deleteButton setFrame:CGRectMake(530, 10, 30, 30)];   //Frame for  iPhone
            [editButton setFrame:CGRectMake(490, 10, 30, 30)];
        }
        else
        {
            [deleteButton setFrame:CGRectMake(440, 10, 30, 30)];  //Frame for iPhone
            [editButton setFrame:CGRectMake(400, 10, 30, 30)];
        }
    }
 }
 else
 {
    //Portrait mode.
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)    //Frame for iPad
    {
        [deleteButton setFrame:CGRectMake(730, 7, 30, 30)];
        [editButton setFrame:CGRectMake(690, 7, 30, 30)];
    }
    else
    {
        [deleteButton setFrame:CGRectMake(280, 7, 30, 30)];     //Frame for iPhone
        [editButton setFrame:CGRectMake(240, 7, 30, 30)];
    }
 }

 [cell.contentView addSubview:editButton];      //Added button subview to cell.
 [cell.contentView addSubview:deleteButton];

 cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

 return cell;   //This code is being executed perfectly in iOS 6 also.
```

I am developing an universal app. But when I am running the app, in iOS 7 it's running perfectly fine, where as in case of iOS 6, the custom edit & delete buttons appear for the first time when the screen is loading. But then when I change the Orientation, it disappears from the screen. I am reloading the table view while changing the Orientations, but still it disappears. Can anyone help me please. Struck at the final point of the project.

Comment: First of all I wouldn't base on the UIDeviceOrientation in this case if you only want to distinguish between landscape and portrait as the device orientation might also by face up and down. Use UIInterfaceOrientation and (if it is a view controller self.interfaceOrientation). Then I would have to debug it to see what is wrong exactly but you did that frame setting in a very bad way. Try to use autoresizing masks as I assume you could refer in your case to some corner points, one code with minor conditions for all cases not such a big if/else

Comment: as you said about iOS versions maybe you placed the code for switching frames in a wrong method which is not called. from where do you call this?

Comment: I reloadData on my table view in "willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:", So every time cellForRowAtIndexPath is being executed whenever I change the interfaceOrientation. And I debugged also, the code for frame is being executed properly but it not displaying.

Comment: maybe sett in simulator Debug->Color Blended layers and maybe it will be helpful as you will see how the frames are changing and where they are

Comment: Tried but didn't work.. But anyway thanks, I fixed the issues with some more coding for Orientations. Can you provide me any link which could point me in a proper direction to do generic coding for handling autoresizing for iOS devices. I tried to learn little bit of auto layout also but it's confusing.

Comment: generally look for using of auto resizing masks (example from stack [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5169517/autoresizing-mask-flexible-width-of-an-image-with-fixed-height))

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this code is in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, you are adding `deleteButton` and `editButton` as subviews of the cell any time to table has to make a new cell (e.g., during a scroll, orientation change, or call to `-reloadData`).  Because the cells are reused, you are most likely getting into a situation where the buttons are removed from the subview when `[cell.contentView addSubview:editButton]` is called on another cell.  Thus the button's `frame` is probably correct, but just in another cell in the table.

If you post the full `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and where the buttons are created then I can help you fix it.